# NullPointerException on getting current location value (lat, lng) Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, nullpointerexception

My code on getting current location is working when I'm using map fragment, but when I use it in another class without displaying the map, I'm getting nullpointerException in String provider. Can you please check what's wrong with my program and if possible explain why I'm getting this error.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_school_list, container, false);
    lvList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvSchools);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService("location");
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    final Location currentLoc = locationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (currentLoc != null) {
        onLocationChanged(currentLoc);
    }

    if (Distance==true){
        double lat = currentLoc.getLatitude();
        double lng = currentLoc.getLongitude();
        ArrayList<Double> rangeList = getRangeList(lat, lng);
        ArrayList<String> theList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int count = 0; count < rangeList.size(); count++)
        {
            String temp = sTuition[count];
            theTuitionFee = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            for(int subloop=0; subloop<sSpecialty[count].length; subloop++) {
            List<String> values = (List<String>)thisFilter[4];
            if (rangeList.get(count) <= DistanceVal
                    &&sReg[count].equalsIgnoreCase((String)thisFilter[0])
                    && sAdmin[count].equalsIgnoreCase((String)thisFilter[1])
                    && sAmbience[count].equalsIgnoreCase((String)thisFilter[3])
                    && amountTF >= theTuitionFee
                    && filtered(sSpecialty[count][subloop], values)) {
                theList1.add(sList[count]);

            }
            }
        }

        displayNearbyList(theList1);
    }
```

Here's my methods:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double currentLat = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLng = location.getLongitude();

}
```

And also getting error with getSystemService and my IDE requires me to put this

```
 private LocationManager getSystemService(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

which is not used in my other working class.

Here's my stack trace . I'm new here , so I don't know how to post stack trace properly

08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at capstone.app.recommender.SchoolListFragmentFilter.onCreateView(SchoolListFragmentFilter.java:67)
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-29 12:14:45.017: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please provide your stack trace

Comment: What is the error you are getting, post logs. Post the Code where its not working.

Comment: I already mention it , here's where i'm getting the error . 
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
I'm new here so I dont know how to add stack trace sorry . wait I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

You should replace your line

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService("location");
```

With this one

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)<your context>.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: I see , now I understand what's wrong , getSystemService does not support non activity class so I need to pass my context

Answer (score 0):

```
 private LocationManager getSystemService(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

This is the method you have to imlpement by yourself, as you return **null**. the `locationManager` below is **null**, and therefore throws NullPointerException

```
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

check the post below to know how should you implement `getSystemService()`

[How does getSystemService() work exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137247/how-does-getsystemservice-work-exactly)